# Multipathing on VMware ESXi is missing

Tags: vmware-esxi, iscsi, multipath

I'm trying to configure a storage multipathing on VMware web client.
I'm running the version 6.5.0, build 6765664.
The problem is that on my storage section I can't find the option about multipathing.

Someone could give me an advice? Maybe is not supported in the web client? I remember that I've used that function on the old windows app.

[image: Here the screen of my ESXi]

Comment: Select the Datastore -- "Configure" tab -- "Connectivity and Multipathing" on the left.

Comment: I've added an image showing the problem.

Comment: You're using the vSphere Web Client but you need to use the vSphere Client to access those settings. The vSphere Web Client is Flash based while the vSphere Client is HTML5 based. If this is a standalone host and not being managed by vCenter Server you can install the embedded Host client on the host. - https://labs.vmware.com/flings/esxi-embedded-host-client

Answer (score 2):

Configuration of multipathing can be done via the thick desktop client (even for 6.5) or via CLI or SSH in the server. 
cmdlets for the SSH - https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1017760

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003973

Comment: The C# thick client does not work with ESXi v6.5...  The only way without a vSphere Server that I find is via CLI.  There is a good article here> https://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1944878&seqNum=8